# How can I select the most recent and distinct records using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to get the latest status of a recorded from a history of statuses using LINQ. I'm having trouble with my order or maybe I'm completely off the mark.

My Code

```
Dim LatestStatusTable= (From RecordHistoryTable In db.RecordHistory) _
    .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Status).[Select](Function(i) i.First())
```

Example Data

```
Data

ID    Timestamp                 Status
251   2017-07-19 11:01:15.577   2
250   2017-07-14 16:15:38.543   2
249   2017-07-13 13:31:13.010   2
249   2017-07-14 04:16:08.307   1
249   2017-07-14 05:45:38.437   2
249   2017-07-14 08:00:42.253   1
249   2017-07-14 08:30:02.380   2
248   2017-07-11 15:30:28.223   2
248   2017-07-11 18:31:11.857   1
248   2017-07-11 18:49:08.510   2

Desired Output

ID    Timestamp                 Status
251   2017-07-19 11:01:15.577   2
250   2017-07-14 16:15:38.543   2
249   2017-07-14 08:30:02.380   2
248   2017-07-11 18:49:08.510   2
```

Can someone please educate me and point me in the right direction?

Comment: `orderByDescending(...)` ?

Comment: Group by Id then when selecting you want to order by timestamp descending then take first in each group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupBy `ID` then when selecting, you want to `OrderByDescending` on `Timestamp`, then take the `First` in each group.

```
Dim LatestStatusTable = (From RecordHistoryTable In db.RecordHistory) _
    .GroupBy(Function(i) i.ID) _
    .[Select](Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Timestamp).First())
```