# How can I select the most recent and distinct records and then count the different result types using LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Follow up question to my original post [How can I select the most recent and distinct records using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225495/)

Example Data

```
Data

ID    Timestamp                 Status
251   2017-07-19 11:01:15.577   2
250   2017-07-14 16:15:38.543   2
249   2017-07-13 13:31:13.010   2
249   2017-07-14 04:16:08.307   1
249   2017-07-14 05:45:38.437   2
249   2017-07-14 08:00:42.253   1
249   2017-07-14 08:30:02.380   2
248   2017-07-11 15:30:28.223   2
248   2017-07-11 18:31:11.857   1


Desired Output

ID    Timestamp                 Status
251   2017-07-19 11:01:15.577   2
250   2017-07-14 16:15:38.543   2
249   2017-07-14 08:30:02.380   2
248   2017-07-11 18:49:08.510   1


Final Results 

Type 1 Type 2
1      3
```

How to group and count the status types by most recent? My code the will compile only gives me the count without it being the most recent status.

```
Dim StatusCount= From item In db.RecordHistory
                             Group By Key = item.Status Into Xs = Group
                             Select New With {.Status = Key, .Count = Xs.Count}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the previous question we were able to get the Desired output like

```
Dim LatestStatusTable = (From RecordHistoryTable In db.RecordHistory) _
    .GroupBy(Function(i) i.ID) _
    .[Select](Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Timestamp).First())
```

From there you just need to group by `Status` in the result that was returned previously

```
Dim StatusCount = From item In LatestStatusTable
                  Group By Key = item.Status Into Xs = Group
                  Select New With {.Status = Xs.Key, .Count = Xs.Count()}
```

Comment: Had no idea you could use the dynamic table data like that. Thank you!

Comment: Seeing query syntax and lambda syntax in the same expression causes me pain.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Enumerable extension methods, 
for your first question 
you can order by id descending, 
for your second question 
you can get the list, and use where extension method, where status equals the type you want, and then use count extension method, same for the other type, this way you can count both.

Here you can check the methods I mentioned if you don't know them already.

[Descending Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

[where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.110).aspx)